# How would I go about creating the calculations in my program?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a "simple cash register" program for school. The program should ask the user for 5 purchase amounts, apply a constant tax rate to the purchase amounts and then display the sub total. Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
// Declare and initialize necessary variables
// You need to use floats for these 

const float TAXRATE = 0.07; // 7% tax rate

float item1 = 0.0, item2 = 0.0, item3 = 0.0, item4 = 0.0, item5 = 0.0;

float subTotal = 0.0, taxTotal = 0.0, totalDue = 0.0; 

float itemPurchases[5];

// Take 5 items as input

// Get item amounts from user

for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter a purchased item" <<endl;
    cin >> itemPurchases[i];
}

// Calculate subTotal, taxTotal, and totalDue

subTotal = itemPurchases[5];

taxTotal = subTotal * TAXRATE;

totalDue = subTotal + taxTotal;

// Drop down two lines on the output and print receipt header

cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Here is your receipt\n" << endl;

// Output the items

cout << fixed << setprecision(2); // Make sure all numbers have 2 decimals 
cout << setw(15) << "Item 1 costs: $" << setw(10) << right << item1 << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Item 2 costs: $" << setw(10) << right << item2 << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Item 3 costs: $" << setw(10) << right << item3 << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Item 4 costs: $" << setw(10) << right << item4 << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Item 5 costs: $" << setw(10) << right << item5 << endl;

// Output single separation line 

cout << "----------------------------" << endl;

// Output subTotals

cout << setw(15) << right << "Subtotal: $" << setw(10) << right << subTotal << endl;
cout << setw(15) << right << "Tax Total: $" << setw(10) << right << taxTotal << endl;

// Output double separation line 

cout << "==========================" << endl;

cout << setw(15) << right << "Total Due: $" << setw(10) << right << totalDue << endl;

// End of program

return 0;
}
```

When I run the program this is what I get:

```
Please enter a purchased item
5.00
Please enter a purchased item
6.00
Please enter a purchased item
7.00
Please enter a purchased item
8.00
Please enter a purchased item
9.00


Here is your receipt

Item 1 costs: $      0.00
Item 2 costs: $      0.00
Item 3 costs: $      0.00
Item 4 costs: $      0.00
Item 5 costs: $      0.00
----------------------------
    Subtotal: $      0.00
   Tax Total: $      0.00
==========================
   Total Due: $      0.00
```

My question is what should I add to the program for actual number amounts to be displayed instead of 0.00?

Comment: You should add code that calculates the subTotal amount from particular itemPurchases like the comments says.

subTotal = itemPurchases[5] is just wrong because you are indexing out of the range (indexing starts from 0).

What you should do is pay attention at your classes and do your homework.

Comment: If your code doesn't work and you don't know why, *try something simpler*. Try to write code that accepts one value and displays it; then maybe you'll see that in the code above, you are reading values into one set of variables, and printing the contents of another.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a accurate code

Add ITEMAMOUNT  as a const value:

```
constexpr float ITEMAMOUNT = 5; // Item Amount (5)
```

Remove this variables:

```
float item1 = 0.0, item2 = 0.0, item3 = 0.0, item4 = 0.0, item5 = 0.0;
```

Use a vector of floats

```
vector<float> itemPurchases(ITEMAMOUNT);
```

Use new for style

```
for (auto& item : itemPurchases)
{
    cout << "Please enter a purchased item" << endl;
    cin >> item;
    subTotal += item;
}
```

use a for to print items

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemPurchases.size(); i++)
{
    cout << setw(15) << "Item "<<i<<" costs: $" << setw(10) << right << itemPurchases[i] << endl;
}
```

Actually, you can do more improvements on your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are storing the cost of the items in an array called itemPurchases, however when you display the cost of each item, you are displaying them from variables initialized to 0.0 when the program began, and never changed. Also, when you calculate the subtotal, you are just assigning it a single value (which is out of bounds since an array's subscript begins at 0). You likely want to get the subtotal by adding all the elements of the array. I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

subTotal = itemPurchases[5];

Here You are trying to access the 6th index in a 5 index array..

Also you are making the subTotal equal to only one item in the array (not the sum of all items)

Why not just increment the subtotal inside the for loop while entering each purchase?